# Access VPN Connected in VMWare Windows 10 in Macbook Bigsur

Tags: network, big-sur, vpn, vmware, proxy

I have Macbook Pro which has windows installed in VMWare Fusion. I have VPN installed inside windows 10 and i can connect and access websites.

Is there a way i can connect VPN in windows and proxy it to Mac via some port or something ?

I'm just thinking out loud.

Thanks,

Comment: Is there a reason not to use a macOS VPN client instead?

Comment: VPN Client not supported in Mac OS. @Scottmeup

Answer (score 1):

With the Fusion guest using bridged networking, a VPN client in the Fusion guest can connect to an external VPN service provider.  As you have discovered - and that is what I use.

What used to work (Fusion 11, macOS 10.15) is that with NAT networking ("Share with my Mac") it was relatively straightforward for the Fusion guest to connect to the outside world using the VPN client software running on the host Mac. This is no longer possible with Fusion 12 and macOS 11.

There has been discussion (some over my head) on the Fusion forum. Have a read of [Sharing host VPN with guest](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Fusion-Discussions/Share-host-VPN-with-guest/m-p/2301323) which discusses solutions using the Fusion bridge device and packet filter rules. But not for the faint hearted.